# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, yolo

I am training pytorch-yolov3 in custom dataset. I prepared all the required txt, data and names files .

while runninng following command:

`python3 train.py --model_def config/yolov3.cfg --data_config config/custom.data`

I got following error:

```
Warning: indexing with dtype torch.uint8 is now deprecated, please use a dtype torch.bool instead. (expandTensors at /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/IndexingUtils.h:20)
Warning: indexing with dtype torch.uint8 is now deprecated, please use a dtype torch.bool instead. (expandTensors at /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/IndexingUtils.h:20)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 136, in <module>
    logger.list_of_scalars_summary(tensorboard_log, batches_done)
  File "/home/sudip/torch/PyTorch-YOLOv3/utils/logger.py", line 16, in list_of_scalars_summary
    summary = tf.summary(value=[tf.summary.Value(tag=tag, simple_value=value) for tag, value in tag_value_pairs])
  File "/home/sudip/torch/PyTorch-YOLOv3/utils/logger.py", line 16, in <listcomp>
    summary = tf.summary(value=[tf.summary.Value(tag=tag, simple_value=value) for tag, value in tag_value_pairs])
AttributeError: module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute 'Value'
```

This is `logger.py`  file:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, log_dir):
        self.writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir)

    def scalar_summary(self, tag, value, step):
        """Log a scalar variable."""
        summary = tf.summary(value=[tf.summary.Value(tag=tag, simple_value=value)])
        self.writer.add_summary(summary, step)

    def list_of_scalars_summary(self, tag_value_pairs, step):
        """Log scalar variables."""
        summary = tf.summary(value=[tf.summary.Value(tag=tag, simple_value=value) for tag, value in tag_value_pairs])
        self.writer.add_summary(summary, step)
```

Any idea or suggestions to solve this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that you posted the correct file? The error is complaining that you are calling `tf.value` in `list_of_scalars_summary`, but the code provided correctly calls `tf.summary.Value`

Comment: Sorry, Now I have added the right file which i got from opensource. Still shows same error .

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
summary = tf.summary(value=[tf.summary.Value(tag=tag, simple_value=value)])
```

To

```
summary = tf.summary.scalar(tag=tag, simple_value=value)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was due to the code being in TF 1.x while I have TF 2.x. So just replacing `self.tf.Summary` with `tf.compat.v1.Summary` (as [dspencer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6083378/dspencer) suggested) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After updating your `logger.py` file to the version actually being called from `train.py`, the error

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorboard.summary._tf.summary' has no attribute 'Value'
```

occurs. This is likely because you are using tensorflow 2.1.0 whereas the `logger.py` script, from an open source project, uses an earlier version of tensorflow with a different API.

Comment: I edited it and updated my question.Still gives me same error. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of Tensorflow are you using? From the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar), scalar summaries are to be written using `tf.summary.scalar`.

Comment: I am using 2.1.0. I also tried to replace `tf.summary` by `tf.compat.v1.summary` but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Thought so. If you say the `logger.py` file came from an open source project, I expect it was designed to use an earlier version of Tensorflow. You may want to have a go at updating the script for 2.1.0.

Comment: You may update your question with the steps you took to try to solve the problem, e.g. using `tf.compat.v1.summary` and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the recent version of TensorFlow, you should modify logger.py as follows:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self, log_dir):
        """Create a summary writer logging to log_dir."""
        self.writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(log_dir) 

    def scalar_summary(self, tag, value, step):
        """Log a scalar variable."""
        with self.writer.as_default():
            tf.summary.scalar(tag, value, step=step)
            self.writer.flush()

    def list_of_scalars_summary(self, tag_value_pairs, step):
        """Log scalar variables."""
        with self.writer.as_default():
            for tag, value in tag_value_pairs:
                tf.summary.scalar(tag, value, step=step)
            self.writer.flush()
```